# URI string into german string with umlaut

Tags: c#, string

I have a URI String ("Franz%C3%B6sisch"). How can I converte it into a string with the german umlaut ("Französisch")?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a web app, use [System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urldecode?view=netframework-4.7.2). Outside a web app, use [System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.urldecode?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_WebUtility_UrlDecode_System_String_). For example:

```
using System;
using System.Net;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(WebUtility.UrlDecode("Franz%C3%B6sisch"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the UrlDecode Methode in [System.Net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.urldecode?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_WebUtility_UrlDecode_System_String_)

```
WebUtility.UrlDecode("%C3%B6")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below logic,
https://dotnetfiddle.net/fyPgvG

System. Net has WebUtility class, you can use UrlDecode method from it.

```
WebUtility. UrlDecode("Franz%C3%B6sisch");
```